# Spring test throws constraint primary key error while creating and how to add Authorization header to request?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-test

i have integration test to create entity like this:

```
@Test
void shouldCreateCategory() throws Exception {
    var createDTO = new CreateDTO();
    createDTO.setName("testCategory");
    createDTO.setSection(0);
    String json = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(createDTO);
    mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/category/create").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(json))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(201));
}
```

But while testing it throws DataIntegrityViolationException could not execute statement SQL constraint [category.PRIMARY], only when i add categories on startup to another tests in import.sql file:

```
insert into section (id, name) values (0, 'test');
insert into category (id, name, section_id) values (0, "testGet", 0);
insert into category (id, name, section_id) values (1, "testDelete", 0);
insert into category (id, name, section_id) values (2, "testRename", 0);
insert into category (id, name, section_id) values (3, "testRename400", 0);
```

Here's my logic of application:

Entity:

```
package com.revo.myboard.category;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.revo.myboard.post.Post;
import com.revo.myboard.section.Section;

/*
 * Created By Revo
 */

@Entity
public final class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Post> posts;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="section_id")
    private Section section;
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }
    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }
    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }
    public void setSection(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
    
}
```

Service:

```
package com.revo.myboard.category;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.revo.myboard.section.SectionService;

/*
 * Created By Revo
 */

@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {
    
    private CategoryRepository repository;
    private SectionService serverService;
    
    public CategoryService(CategoryRepository repository, SectionService serverService) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.serverService = serverService;
    }

    public void createCategory(String name, long section_id) {
        if(repository.existsByName(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name);
        }
        var category = new Category();
        category.setName(name);
        category.setSection(serverService.getSectionById(section_id));
        repository.save(category);
    }
    
    public void deleteCategoryById(long id) {
        repository.delete(getCategoryById(id));

    }

    public Category getCategoryById(long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException(String.valueOf(id)));
    }
    
    public void renameCategoryById(long id, String new_name) {
        if(repository.existsByName(new_name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(new_name);
        }
        getCategoryById(id).setName(new_name);
    }
    
}
```

Contoller:

```
package com.revo.myboard.category;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.revo.myboard.category.dto.CategoryDTO;
import com.revo.myboard.category.dto.CreateDTO;
import com.revo.myboard.category.dto.NameDTO;
import com.revo.myboard.security.annotation.ForAdmin;

/*
 *  Created By Revo
 */

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category")
@Validated
public class CategoryController {

    private CategoryService categoryService;
    
    public CategoryController(CategoryService categoryService) {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }
    
    
    /*
     * PUBLIC
     */
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public CategoryDTO getCategoryById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return new CategoryDTO().mapFromCategory(categoryService.getCategoryById(id));
    }

    /*
     *  ADMIN
     */

    @PostMapping("/create")
    @ForAdmin
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createCategory(@RequestBody @Valid CreateDTO createDTO) {
        categoryService.createCategory(createDTO.getName(), createDTO.getSection());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    @ForAdmin
    public void deleteCategoryByName(@PathVariable long id) {
        categoryService.deleteCategoryById(id);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/rename/{id}")
    public void renameCategoryByName(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody @Valid NameDTO renameDTO) {
        categoryService.renameCategoryById(id, renameDTO.getNewName());
    }
    
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.revo.myboard.category;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/*
 * Created By Revo
 */

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    /*
     * FIND CATEGORY BY NAME
     */
    
    Optional<Category> findByName(String name);
    
    /*
     * EXISTS BY NAME
     */
    
    boolean existsByName(String name);
    
}
```

Changing generation strategy to identity strategy helps, but it changing id's of data from import.sql and i can't test another methods, because i refer to contoller methods by this id.

And i have second problem, i get unauthorized in this test:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
void shouldCreateComment() throws Exception {
    var createDTO = new CreateDTO();
    createDTO.setContent("testComment");
    createDTO.setPost(0);
    String json = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(createDTO);
    mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/comment/create").contentType(Utils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(json))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(201));
}
```

Only when i add @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token in contoller, without it i didn't get an error, but i need this token to get client data while comment creating, how add this header in test?

Comment: Okay, i change stategety to identity and it works, before i have error in getting test because i invoke to 0, iteration starts from 1, so now how add header token to test?

Comment: Post to close, i fix it, before i perform request to end point i perform login and getting header, then paste it to header in request like this:

Comment: @Test
 void shouldCreateComment() throws Exception {
  var createDTO = new CreateDTO();
  createDTO.setContent("testComment");
  createDTO.setPost(1);
  String json = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(createDTO);
  mockMvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/comment/create").header("Authorization", Utils.getTokenForUser(mockMvc, objectMapper)).contentType(Utils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(json))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(201));
 }

Comment: public static String getTokenForUser(MockMvc mockMvc, ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws Exception {
  var credentialsDTO = new CredentialsDTO();
  credentialsDTO.setLogin("test");
  credentialsDTO.setPassword("test");
  String json = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(credentialsDTO);
  return mockMvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login").contentType(Utils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(json))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(200)).andReturn().getResponse().getHeader("Authorization");
 }